Place "short title" and a link to the site's scope on to the home page of each Stackexchange site
Since users struggle to find[1][2] the scope of Stackexchange sites, it would be helpful to place a link (to the definition of the site's scope) on to the welcome page (home page) of each Stackexchange site.
Maybe also display the site's "short title" on its homepage (i.e. "Server Fault: Q&A for system and network administrators") as listed in all sites.
Benefits:

This would guide users in finding the correct site easier.
This would contribute to keeping questions within the site's scope.


Or more prominently on the ask-question page (it's there, but not very prominent).

"Users struggle to find" links to your own question, which is not really what I would call representative of "users" :)
